# How do I get Cobblestone in Minecraft PE?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Whenever I play survival in Minecraft Pocket Edition, I can't seem to find any cobblestone at all!

Where can it be?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to craft a [pickaxe](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Pickaxe) and mine [stone](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Stone) to get [cobblestone](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Cobblestone).

Stone turns into cobblestone when mined with a pickaxe.

[image: Stone][image: Cobblestone]

You should use this cobblestone to craft better tools and build a house..

Read [this](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Pocket_Edition), it might help you get started.

Comment: +1 for the link. It's good to see that people aren't out to answer the question, but are out to _help_.

Comment: Thank you so much!I thought I never would get an answer!

Answer (score 1):

Cobblestone can be found about ~4 blocks below the dirt. Just mine the dirt, and then you should find stone. Mine the stone and you will get cobblestone.

Answer (score -1):

When Stone(ID:1) is broken with a wooden pickaxe or stronger, (I.E. Stone Pickaxe, Gold Pickaxe, Iron Pickaxe, Diamond Pickaxe) it gives you 1(One) Cobblestone.

Comment: This was already answered with same answer last year. Dupe answers arent allowed here and will be removed. Also misleading name might result in an account removak.